# Как из окна Window1 поменять значение textblock в Window2?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, форумчане.

Задача:

Существует 2 окна Window1 и Window2.

При нажатии на кнопку btn1 в Window1 должно поменяться значение Textblock в Window2.
Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Мои попытки:

1) создаем метод в Window2:

```
    public void DoUpadte(string name)
    {
        this.LoginNameTextBox.Text = name;
    }
```

2) обращаемся к нему из Window1:

```
DoUpdate(text);
```

Ошибка:

> Элемент "DoUpdate" не существует в
> текущем контексте.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что "DoUpdate" не существует в текущем контексте. :) Для того что бы ее вызвать, вам нужна ссылка на конкретный экземпляр Window2.

Как-то так:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private Window2 wnd_2;

    public Window1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void MenuItem_Wnd2_Create(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         wnd_2 = new Window2();
         wnd_2.Show();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Wnd2_TextEdit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (wnd_2 == null) return;
         wnd_2.DoUpdate("Hello");
    }    
}
```

В случае если окна создаются независимо, вам придется где-то хранить хендл на КОНКРЕТНОЕ окно Window2 и в нужный момент передавать его в КОНКРЕТНОЕ окно Window1.